# How can I import data from a CSV file to a Postgres database in a transaction with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, transactions, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a web app, in which a user can upload a CSV file with some data. I'd like to insert the data to the database, but as a transaction; either the whole CSV data gets inserted or non at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibilty that application call the PostgreSQL client API (libpq) to use the SQL COPY command but I don't know if this is possible with ASP.NET Core.

See COPY command https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html
and COPY functions in libpq https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-copy.html